# Maven run plugin goal and preceding phases

Tags: maven

Usually when we run a plugin goal in maven directly from the command line, the build phases preceding the one the plugin goal is bound to will not be run.

How can we run the plugin goal and all its preceding build phases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special support for this. But you can call

`mvn preceding-phase goal:you-want-to-call`

which will be essentially what you want.